# jquery last addclass

Tags: jquery

i have four boxes that are styled with css and sit side by side with a margini on the right. for the last box i am adding a class that removes the right margin so they all sit on the same line.

here is the jquery that is in the `<head>`

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){          
        $('div.home-features:last').addClass('last');   
     });  
</script>
```

here is the code generated

```
<div class="content-box2-top"><!-- no content--></div>
<div class="content-box2-center">    

        <div class="home-features">
            <h2>Services</h2>
            <span class="content">
                One point of contact for your international operations eliminating the need for multiple relationships.<br />

            </span>
            <a class="read" href="/getdoc/762a1cb8-2492-4844-8401-5037e7c30afc/Services">Read More</a>
        </div>

        <div class="home-features">
            <h2>Process</h2>
            <span class="content">
                Global access to your accounts, 24 hours a day through our secure online accounting portal.
            </span>

            <a class="read" href="/getdoc/6c7b45da-4e86-44fa-9a15-6d1298576b8a/Process">Read More</a>
        </div>

        <div class="home-features">
            <h2>Benefits</h2>
            <span class="content">
                Alleviating the burden of recruiting and managing in-house accounting teams.
            </span>
            <a class="read" href="/getdoc/592b78e1-f17f-498e-b3bb-f159e4c2d348/Benefits">Read More</a>

        </div>

        <div class="home-features">
            <h2>Reach</h2>
            <span class="content">
                Drawing on the local knowledge and expertise of our partner firms around the world.
            </span>
            <a class="read" href="/getdoc/9e82f2b8-7aaa-417d-9c23-a235c4ff26fd/Reach">Read More</a>
        </div>


</div>
<div class="content-box2-bottom"><!-- no conetnt --></div>
```

the problem is that when the page loads there is a delay in adding the "last" class to the last element. so it appears under the other three and then pings in to place!

how can i stop it from doing this and just appear inline?

Answer (score 1):

My own preference would be to use direct css, rather than jQuery:

```
content-box2-center > div:last,
content-box2-center > div:last-child {
    /* CSS here */
}
```

You could, of course, use a different approach:

```
content-box2-center {
    visibility: hidden;
    /* or display: none; */
}
```

with the jQuery {

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('div.home-features:last').addClass('last');
        $('content-box-center').show();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of the page still loading. `$(document).ready(function(){` only happens when the page is loaded.

I'm not sure, but if you just moved `$('div.home-features:last').addClass('last');` to be after "content-box2-bottom" then I think it would happen even without the rest of the page loading.

Comment: Moving the JavaScript code won't make a jot of difference. That's the whole point of document.ready

Comment: It will if there's a huge amount of code following the content-box2-bottom. It's worth trying if the OP can't add the `last` class using ASP (which is by far the preferable way).

Answer (score 0):

The document.ready code is executed when the page is ready to be manipulated. This will probably be the cause of the delay.

Can you not just specify the `last` class on the `div`:

```
<div class="home-features last">
```

This means it will arrive on the page with this class in place without having to wait untill its loaded before applying.

Comment: And what is the data source? If you can generate some metadata that stipluates when a row is the last one (and is blank otherwise), you can include that in some `<% %>` within the class attribute.